# Build isomorphism from subset of non-injective homomorphism?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Given two vector-spaces $V, W$ with $\dim(V)=5$ and $\dim(W)=2$.

If there exists a surjective homomorphism $f:V \to W$, does there exist a subspace of the domain: $V_1 \subset V$ with $\dim(V_1)= 2$ isomorphic to $W$?

Since $V$ is larger than $W$ and $f$ is surjective, it makes sense that we can choose a subset of the domain to reach $W$.

> But is this subset necesarilly a subspace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose a basis of $W$, say $\{w_1, w_2\}$ take an element $v_1$ in the inverse image of $w_1$, and take an element $v_2$. (Why aren't these inverse images empty?) Define $V_1$ to be the subspace generated by $v_1$ and $v_2$, this is the subspace you're looking for and restricting $f$ to $V_1$ is an isomorphism.

To finish this proof show that $f$ is injective and surjective.

Comment: Makes sense. I was so focused on $V$ that I didn't think to construct $V_1$ based on W. Thanks for the tip, that helped.

Answer (score 0):

A general result on vector spaces and linear maps is the following.

*Suppose $f\colon V\to W$ is a linear map and that $\{v_1,\dots,v_k\}$ is a set in $V$. If $\{f(v_1),\dots,f(v_k)\}$ is linearly independent, then also $\{v_1,\dots,v_k\}$ is linearly independent.*

Just take scalars so that $a_1v_1+\dots+a_kv_k=0$; then also $a_1f(v_1)+\dots+a_kf(v_k)=f(0)=0$ and therefore $a_1=\dots=a_k=0$.

Whenever you have a surjective linear map $f\colon V\to W$, you can choose $\{v_1,\dots,v_k\}$ so that $\{f(v_1),\dots,f(v_k)\}$ is a basis of $W$.

Now you can finish.